# Modify bst file so that 2 authors are separated by "and" in the text

Tags: citing, custom-bib

I have to work with a custom .bst file for a paper. When I have exactly two authors for a reference, these authors are separated **in text** with " , ".
So e.g. (Simonyan , Zisserman, 2014). I want it to be (Simonyan and Zisserman, 2014).
In my bibliography the style is correct.
So, is it necessary to change the .bst file?
I think here are the relevant lines:

```
INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }

FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  'f :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr f format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { ", " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" author format.names }
  if$
}
```

Comment: It is quite likely that you would have to change the `.bst` style, yes (though I think there are some styles that use user-definable macros that could be changed in the `.tex` file directly, I don't think this style is one of them). I must admit that I rarely get things right the first time when I play around with `.bst` files and so it would help me greatly if you could provide the entire `.bst` file (it is probably too large to fit here, so upload it to a text sharing site like https://pastebin.com/ or https://gist.github.com/) and a short test file (`.tex` and `.bib`).

Comment: It is the recent ISPRS template. All files can be found on: http://www.isprs.org/documents/orangebook/app5.aspx 
The template has been modified recently and is now inconsistent (the point I mentioned can be seen in 3.5.8) with the MS Word template. The deadline of my paper is quite soon and I cannot wait until there is an update. Nonetheless, I don't want to switch to Word ;).
The function format.names begins at line 158.

Comment: FWIW I think it should help to turn the second occurrence of `{ ", " * t * }` into `{ " and " * t * }` but I could be wrong.

Comment: Nope, just looked at the `.bst` it should be a different place. Hang on a sec...

Comment: Tested it. That changed the last author of a reference in the bibliography to be separated with an "and" and not a comma. Nice to know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant macro is `format.lab.names.abbr`. For the "and" it has to read

```
FUNCTION {format.lab.names.abbr}
{ 's :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames #1 >
    { numnames #2 >
        { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ " et al." * }
        { s #2 "{ff }{vv }{ll}{ jj}" format.name$ "others" =
            { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ " et al." * }
            { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ " and " *
              s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * 
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ }
  if$
}
```

the change is in the second branch of the innermost conditional. The version of `isprs.bst` currently available at http://www.isprs.org/documents/orangebook/app5.aspx has

```
s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ " , " * % replaced and with ,
```

there and we make it read

```
s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ " and " *
```

again. Note their comment and the spurious whitespace before the comma.

---

Of course you should still report this issue to the maintainer of the template and you should not modify the `.bst` file directly. Only modify and renamed copy, `isprs-and.bst` say, and document the changes.

Comment: Yeah, I am already in contact with the new maintainer. Weird that there is that comment.... Thank you for helping this fast.